# Let changes be accepted only by admin in Google Docs

Tags: google-docs, permissions

I have a Google Docs document and I want to let everybody with the link suggest changes on it, so an admin would accept the correct changes on the document.

I just found the "suggesting" mode, but it is meaningless, since a person with the link and permission to edit can change it directly and won't bother to use suggestion mode.

How can I put all changes the users make as edit suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

People with commenting privileges can only suggest edits to documents, so give those who you would only allow suggesting changes the comment privilege on the document and those who approve the changes editing access to the document.

On the advanced page, it is possible to set the link access to comment.